# What layout should I use to make this work for Java?

Tags: java, layout, gridbaglayout

Here's what I want the end result to look like...

[image: Pizza Shop Menu]

I am trying to use a GridBagLayout for this but not sure if its the right choice because it's coming out all over the place.  I know I shouldn't write all my code in a single constructor but here's what I have so far...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;


public class HomeStylePizza extends JFrame{

    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    //GUI components
    private JLabel lblEachTopping, lblPizzaSize, lblPizzaType, lblWelcome, lblYourOrder;

    private JButton btnProcessSelection;

    private JCheckBox cbPepproni, cbSausage, cbMushrooms, cbPineapple, cbOnion, cbBellPepper;

    private JRadioButton rbSmall, rbMedium, rbLarge, rbThinCrust, rbMediumCrust, rbPan;

    private ButtonGroup grp1, grp2;

    private JTextArea textArea;

    private CalculateButtonHandler cbHandler;


    public HomeStylePizza()
    {
        //Create new labels
        lblEachTopping = new JLabel("Each Topping: $1.50");
        lblPizzaSize = new JLabel("Pizza Size");
        lblPizzaType = new JLabel("Pizza Type");
        lblWelcome = new JLabel("Welcome to Home Style Pizza Shop");
        lblYourOrder = new JLabel("Your order:");

        //Create new buttons
        btnProcessSelection = new JButton("Process Selection");
        cbHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
        btnProcessSelection.addActionListener(cbHandler);

        //Create new JCheckBoxes
        cbPepproni = new JCheckBox("Pepproni");
        cbSausage = new JCheckBox("Sausage");
        cbMushrooms = new JCheckBox("Mushrooms");
        cbPineapple = new JCheckBox("Pineapple");
        cbOnion = new JCheckBox("Onion");
        cbBellPepper = new JCheckBox("Bell Pepper");

        //Create radio buttons
        rbSmall = new JRadioButton("Small: $6.50");
        rbMedium = new JRadioButton("Medium: $8.50");
        rbLarge = new JRadioButton("Large: $10.00");
        rbThinCrust = new JRadioButton("Thin Crust");
        rbMediumCrust = new JRadioButton("Medium Crust");
        rbPan = new JRadioButton("Pan");

        //Create new TextArea
        textArea = new JTextArea(6, 10);

        //Set title
        setTitle("Pizza Shop");

        //Create new font layout
        Font font = new Font("New Times Roman", Font.BOLD, 18);


        //get the container
        Container pane = getContentPane();

        JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
        thePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        //set the layout
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridheight = 1;
        gridConstraints.weightx = 50;
        gridConstraints.weighty = 100;
        gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gridConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;


        //Place components in the pane
        thePanel.add(lblWelcome, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = 20;
        gridConstraints.gridx = 15;
        lblWelcome.setFont(new Font("New Times Roman", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lblWelcome.setForeground(Color.RED);

        //Create new vertical box and place a titled border around it
        Box optionBox1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        optionBox1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Toppings", 0, 0, new Font("times new roman", Font.PLAIN, 14), Color.RED));
        //add components to optionBox1
        optionBox1.add(lblEachTopping);
        lblEachTopping.setForeground(Color.RED);
        optionBox1.add(cbPepproni);
        optionBox1.add(cbSausage);
        optionBox1.add(cbMushrooms);
        optionBox1.add(cbPineapple);
        optionBox1.add(cbOnion);
        optionBox1.add(cbBellPepper);
        //add optionBox1 to WEST quadrant
        thePanel.add(optionBox1, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 10;



        //Create new vertical box and place a titled border around it
        Box optionBox2 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        optionBox2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Pizza Size", 0, 0, new Font("times new roman", Font.PLAIN, 14), Color.RED));
        //Create new ButtonGroup
        grp1 = new ButtonGroup();

        //add components to optionBox2 and grp1
        grp1.add(rbSmall);
        grp1.add(rbMedium);
        grp1.add(rbLarge);
        optionBox2.add(rbSmall);
        optionBox2.add(rbMedium);
        optionBox2.add(rbLarge);
        //add optionBox2 to CENTER 
        thePanel.add(optionBox2, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gridConstraints.gridx = 3;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 10;


        Box btnBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        btnBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        btnBox.add(btnProcessSelection);
        thePanel.add(btnBox);
        gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = 5;
        gridConstraints.gridx = 3;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 12;



        //Create new vertical box and place a titled border around it
        Box optionBox3 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        optionBox3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Pizza Type", 0, 0, new Font("times new roman", Font.PLAIN, 14), Color.RED));
        //Create new ButtonGroup
        grp2 = new ButtonGroup();

        //add components to optionBox2 and grp1
        grp2.add(rbThinCrust);
        grp2.add(rbMediumCrust);
        grp2.add(rbPan);
        optionBox3.add(rbThinCrust);
        optionBox3.add(rbMediumCrust);
        optionBox3.add(rbPan);
        //add optionBox3 to EAST
        thePanel.add(optionBox3, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridx = 5;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 10;


        //Create box for lblYourOrder and textArea and 
        //add them to pane in SOUTH quadrant
        Box orderBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        orderBox.setBorder(null);
        orderBox.add(lblYourOrder);
        orderBox.add(textArea);
        thePanel.add(orderBox, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = 30;
        gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 13;

        pane.add(thePanel);


        //set window size and display it
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);

        //Center frame
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.pack();


        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }//End of constructor

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HomeStylePizza menuTest = new HomeStylePizza();


    }//End of main

    private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        }

    }




}//End of class
```

Its a bit ugly and you can ignore most of my comments I've been changing things around trying to fix it.  I was using a different layout.

Comment: I would recommend MigLayout http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:  I went ahead and created the Pizza Shop GUI.

[image: Home Style Pizza]

I used a combination of BorderLayouts and GridBagLayouts.

I grouped together the code to make it easier to follow.  Grouping the code does not mean putting all of the JCheckBox initializations together.  Grouping the code means that all of the elements that make up a JPanel are there, right next to each other.  This way, you don't have to jump all over the code looking for the lines that define the JRadioButton rbMedium.

I used a separate GridBagConstraints for each Swing component to make it easier for me to debug the GUI.

I've left the action listener for you to code.

Here's the GUI code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class HomeStylePizza implements Runnable {

    private static final Insets bottomInsets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    private static final Insets normalInsets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);

    // GUI components
    private JCheckBox cbPepproni, cbSausage, cbMushrooms, cbPineapple, cbOnion,
            cbBellPepper;

    private JRadioButton rbSmall, rbMedium, rbLarge, rbThinCrust,
            rbMediumCrust, rbPan;

    private JTextArea textArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new HomeStylePizza());
    } // End of main

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pizza Shop");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        int gridy = 0;

        addComponent(mainPanel, createTitlePanel(), 0, gridy++, 2, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        addComponent(mainPanel, createToppingPanel(), 0, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();
        eastPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        eastPanel.add(createSizePanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        eastPanel.add(new JLabel(" "), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        eastPanel.add(createTypePanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        eastPanel.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        addComponent(mainPanel, eastPanel, 1, gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets,
                GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        addComponent(mainPanel, createTextAreaPanel(), 0, gridy++, 2, 1,
                bottomInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTitlePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel lblWelcome = new JLabel("Welcome to Home Style Pizza Shop");
        Font titleFont = lblWelcome.getFont().deriveFont(20F);
        lblWelcome.setFont(titleFont);
        lblWelcome.setForeground(Color.RED);

        panel.add(lblWelcome);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createToppingPanel() {
        Border redBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2);
        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 10, 4, 10);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(redBorder,
                emptyBorder));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        JLabel lblEachTopping = new JLabel("Each Topping: $1.50");
        lblEachTopping.setForeground(Color.RED);
        panel.add(lblEachTopping);

        cbPepproni = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
        cbSausage = new JCheckBox("Sausage");
        cbMushrooms = new JCheckBox("Mushrooms");
        cbPineapple = new JCheckBox("Pineapple");
        cbOnion = new JCheckBox("Onion");
        cbBellPepper = new JCheckBox("Bell Pepper");

        // add components to optionBox1
        panel.add(cbPepproni);
        panel.add(cbSausage);
        panel.add(cbMushrooms);
        panel.add(cbPineapple);
        panel.add(cbOnion);
        panel.add(cbBellPepper);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createSizePanel() {
        Border redBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2);
        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 10, 4, 10);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(redBorder,
                emptyBorder));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        JLabel lblPizzaSize = new JLabel("Pizza Size");
        lblPizzaSize.setForeground(Color.RED);
        panel.add(lblPizzaSize);

        rbSmall = new JRadioButton("Small: $6.50");
        rbMedium = new JRadioButton("Medium: $8.50");
        rbLarge = new JRadioButton("Large: $10.00");

        // Create new ButtonGroup
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        group.add(rbSmall);
        group.add(rbMedium);
        group.add(rbLarge);

        panel.add(rbSmall);
        panel.add(rbMedium);
        panel.add(rbLarge);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createTypePanel() {
        Border redBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2);
        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 10, 4, 10);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(redBorder,
                emptyBorder));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        JLabel lblPizzaType = new JLabel("Pizza Type");
        lblPizzaType.setForeground(Color.RED);
        panel.add(lblPizzaType);

        rbThinCrust = new JRadioButton("Thin Crust");
        rbMediumCrust = new JRadioButton("Medium Crust");
        rbPan = new JRadioButton("Pan");

        // Create new ButtonGroup
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        // add components to optionBox2 and grp1
        group.add(rbThinCrust);
        group.add(rbMediumCrust);
        group.add(rbPan);

        panel.add(rbThinCrust);
        panel.add(rbMediumCrust);
        panel.add(rbPan);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton btnProcessSelection = new JButton("Process Selection");
        btnProcessSelection.addActionListener(new CalculateButtonHandler());
        panel.add(btnProcessSelection);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createTextAreaPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel lblYourOrder = new JLabel("Your order:");
        panel.add(lblYourOrder, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        textArea = new JTextArea(6, 12);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    private void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
            int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, Insets insets,
            int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
                gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

    private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        }

    }

} // End of HomeStylePizza class
```

Comment: What GUI is strange? The pic I provided or my code haha.  And I am trying to do what your suggesting but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @Marcus: The process selection button should be centered under the 3 pizza panels, in my opinion.  Centering it under the 2 pizza panels seems off to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use GridBagLayout, or use netbeans it will make it easy for you, other option use GridLayout(2,1)

in it 2 panel 
panel 1 will have grid layout of 1,2 in it you first list and other pnael has grid layout of 2,1 first row is your second list and the second row will be the button finally put the order info in the second row of your base layout.

Comment: How would I put the order info in the second row of my base layout?  Do I place empty panels in the slots till I get to the one I want?